# Assigning namespaces for topics from Kinect (Turtlebot)

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, namespace, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am doing a simulation with 2 Turtlebots in Gazebo (using ROS Fuerte). I used different namespaces (turtle1 and turtle2) for each robot in order to get their respective data. However, I noticed that some of the topics (topics with Kinect info) did not change their names. For instance after using this snippet:

```
<group ns="turtle2">
  <include file="$(find tortuninja)/launch/turtlebotNodes.launch" >
    <arg  name="model_name" value="turtle2" /> 
    <arg name="x" value = "-2.0" />
  </include>
</group>
```

Topics like `/imu/data` would become accordingly `/turtle2/imu/data`. But for others like `/camera/depth/points` I would still get `/camera/depth/points`.

I fixed the problem by editing the file `($find turtlebot_description)/urdf/gazebo.urdf.xacro` . I changed the global topic names like `/camera/depth/points` to local ones `camera/depth/points`. After doing that I was able to get the corresponding namespace in front (and get info from both Kinects).

My question is: Is this the right approach? Or is there any other way to change the namespace for Kinect-topics in Turtlebot other than editing the `gazebo.urdf.xacro file`?

Thanks!

Ana

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49034/assigning-namespaces-for-topics-from-kinect-(turtlebot)/) by [Ana](https://answers.ros.org/users/3666/ana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-26**:
There is another way by remapping the global topic names. However as @joq said, your way is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds like a good solution to me.

Open a bug ticket for the turtlebot_description package to get it fixed permanently in a future release.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ana](https://answers.ros.org/users/3666/ana/) on 2012-11-26**:
Done. Thank you very much for the suggestion.